# Bootstrap Grids not working Intel XDK

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, intel, intel-xdk

I am trying to build an app using the Intel XDK and using Bootstrap for the styling and grids. The problem is that when I test the app, the grids don't show up, the text just shows as separate rows rather than columns. [Here is a screenshot I took](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBYOh.jpg)

**Is this an XDK specific problem or something else?**

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap app should work in XDK if all the library files are included as part of the project you create or import. It is possible, if you are using the example right off bootstrap download, the libraries are outside the folder you have imported. Can you verify that you have sourced and included all the associated js and css files for bootstrap. You can open the debug button in the emulator and you should be able to see if there are any console errors.

Comment: Seconded bootstrap works fine, have used with the XDK, even has demo apps with bootstrap,it would be  useful if you posted some code, people here 'spot things' beyond mere mortals